# how to run a django python file from command line

Tags: python, django

I have a simple python file that I eventually want to run from chron.

It looks like this:

```
from customers.models import Customer, NotificationLogEntry


def hello():
    customers =  Customer.objects.all()
    for c in customers:
        log_entry = NotificationLogEntry(
                                          customer=c,
                                          sent=True,
                                          notification_type=0,
                                          notification_media_type=0,
                                          )
        log_entry.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

When I run this with:

```
python notifications.py
```

I get an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notifications.py", line 1, in <module>
    from customers.models import Customer, NotificationLogEntry
ImportError: No module named customers.models
```

This module exists and I call it without any problem within my django app.  Why am I getting this error outside of my app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a custom command

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Or, run `./manage.py shell` then import your file

Or, load the django settings

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Answer (score 6):

Here's super simple option if you're running cron jobs:

```
cat run.py | ./manage.py shell
```

Comment: If you have the `django-extensions` package installed you can use the `./manage.py runscript` command.
https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html

Answer (score 3):

you need to set up project path

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project_name.settings")

# your imports, e.g. Django models
from customers.models import Customer, NotificationLogEntry
```

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly with Python2 and Django1.7 for running python scripts to interact with Django from the command line.